# Is there any approch to handle emojis in database

Tags: ios, mysql, node.js, memoji

I am working on to send emojis and memojis in ios chat application using mysql and nodejs. I did'nt find any documentation related to memojis. I am successfuly send emojis but memojis could'nt save into db.

Does any one know about what type of data is (memojis) ?
what is the best way to store this animated image in mysql?
what could be the approch to handle memojis using nodejs and mysql?

if any one can help it would be really grateful.

Comment: With an immature opinion, could you get the binary byte for memoji just like mp4,jpg, so you can put it into mysql as a blob column.

Comment: issue resolved by converting memoji to .jpg